# UICollectionView select 2 items and it should be one

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a UICollectionView with a UITableView in the same UIViewController but I got an issue where whenever I select an item it select another item and that shouldn't be right.

I saved the item number in NSUserDefault and retrieve it in `-(BOOL)ViewWillAppear` so I can get the selected cell IndexPath

I tried to trace and logging the code but couldn't find the issue it appears that everything is normal and change the background of the selected cell and deselect the previous selected cell but I found that another cell's background is changed which it shouldn't happen.

here is the code :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *cell = (Cell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // collection_flag : if the datasource array is zero it should be true
    if ((collection_rows == 1 && collection_flag) || (indexPath.item == collection_rows) || (indexPath.item == collection_rows-1)) {
        cell.semester.text = @"Add";
    }else{

        NSDictionary *temp = [semesters objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        cell.semester.text = [temp objectForKey:@"SEMESTER_NUMBER"];



    }

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    //changing the selected cell background on appreaing of uicollectionview
    if (indexPath.item == prevCell.item) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return cell;
}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //prevCell is the selected cell indexPath

    if (prevCell == nil) {

        prevCell = indexPath;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:prevCell.item forKey:@"selected cell"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"did select cell"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSLog(@"prevCell didnt exist and now created");

    }else{

        NSLog(@"prevCell item is %d and indexPath %d",prevCell.item , indexPath.item);
        Cell *selectedCell = (Cell *)[collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:prevCell];
        selectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        prevCell = indexPath;
        NSLog(@"new prevCell item is %d",prevCell.item);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:prevCell.item forKey:@"selected cell"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    Cell *cell = (Cell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    if (indexPath.item < collection_rows-1) {

        NSString *semester_number = cell.semester.text;

        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM COURSES WHERE SEMESTER_NUM = '%@'",semester_number];
        semester_details = [DataBase loadFromDataBase:sql];

        if ([semester_details count] > 0 && !isTableVisible) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
                tabel.alpha = 1;
            }];
            [tabel reloadData];

        }else if ([semester_details count] > 0 && isTableVisible)
        {
            [tabel reloadData];

        }else{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
                tabel.alpha = 0;
            }];
        }

    }else{
        Semesters *semester = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"semesterView"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:semester animated:YES];
    }

}
```

UPDATE : here I post `-viewDidLoad` and some other methods

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    semesters = [DataBase loadFromDataBase:@"SELECT * FROM SEMESTER"];
    if (collection_rows == 0) {
        collection_flag = true;
    }

    collection_rows = (int)[semesters count] + 1;
    NSLog(@"Rows : %d",collection_rows);

    tabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    tabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    tabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    tabel.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        collection.alpha = 1;
    }];

    isTableVisible = NO;
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self viewDidLoad];


    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"did select cell"]) {
        item = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selected cell"];
        prevCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"Cell item  = %d",item);
        }

    [collection reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose to change selected cell background and change it back to previous state if another cell selected you are doing it wrong. You should use delegate methods to find selected / deselected cells.

```
// did Select
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

// did deselect 
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

then you should delete following codes from your delegate method.

```
if (prevCell == nil) {

    prevCell = indexPath;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:prevCell.item forKey:@"selected cell"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"did select cell"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"prevCell didnt exist and now created");

}else{

    NSLog(@"prevCell item is %d and indexPath %d",prevCell.item , indexPath.item);
    Cell *selectedCell = (Cell *)[collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:prevCell];
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    prevCell = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"new prevCell item is %d",prevCell.item);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:prevCell.item forKey:@"selected cell"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

Cell *cell = (Cell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and

```
//changing the selected cell background on appreaing of uicollectionview
if (indexPath.item == prevCell.item) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: I implemented the delegates but still whenever I select an item it select another item with it. for example when I choose item 0 it change its background to red and also item 5

Comment: I did as you suggested but still I'm having the same issue , I removed the codes from the delegate methods but that didn't fix my issue

Comment: This how UICollectionView works, what you described is not a expected behaviour, it might be comes from some other piece of code of yours which I can't see.

Comment: Also try clean (shift+alt+cmd+K) your project and delete app from simulator then give a try.

Comment: Sorry for being late to respond but I tried your solutions nothing changed  I post more code please check it if there is a mistake please tell me

Comment: @faisal60 couldn't see anything can cause what you describe. I suggest you should removed everything inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` and try again with the code in my answer.